Run a board game tournament
You are in charge of running a board game tournament.  Unfortunately, you only have one copy of the game and only so much time, so only a limited number of games can be played.  Similarly, you have a bunch of players but the game only accommodates up to four.  Since you want to run the best tournament possible, you want to ensure that the best player wins.
Your task, therefore is to write a function (in python, for ease of running in the controller) which runs a tournament - deciding who plays in which game, comparing results, and ultimately returning who wins.
Spec
def run_tournament(contestants, games, play_game):
  # contestants: an array of contestant names
  # games: a number - this is the maximum number of games you're allowed to play
  # play_game: a function which takes an array of contestants and returns the outcome of a game which they all play

  # returns a single string, expected to be the name of one of the competitors

Each contestant is given a name and a skill value (hidden).  When a game is played, each contestant in the game generates a random integer from 0 to their skill value, and then the list of contestants is sorted based on the numbers generated.
games is guaranteed to be at least (len(contestants)-1)/3, enough that if you eliminate 3 contestants each round, you'll have one winner remaining.
play_game raises an exception if it is given more than four players or a game is started once all the allowed games have been played.  It returns the names of the four players it was passed, sorted so that the winner is first.
Scoring
I will run 100000 games for each entry for each of 4 different tournament setups.  They can be found in the linked repository.  I may add another tournament setup if it appears necessary (in particular, if an entry seems to be abusing some facet of the current setups).
If your function raises an exception, no points are scored.  If your function returns the name of the contestant with the highest skill, you score one point.  The winner is the submission that scores highest on average across all of the tournament setups.  I may accept a winner once at least 2 weeks have passed since the last entry.
Example code
def run_tournament(contestants, games, play_game):
    while len(contestants) > 1:
        winner = play_game(contestants[:4])[0]
        contestants = contestants[4:] + [winner]
    return winner

The controller can be found at https://github.com/Nucaranlaeg/game-tournament.  Create your entry in its own file with a run_tournament function, and run with python main.py <your_entry>
Scores



Entry
Ten weak players
Two groups
Huge pool
32 skilled players
Average




Spitemaster
17793
22161
26550
39507
26503


tsh
17292
22355
25174
34026
24711


example
17858
21276
25967
25402
22625


Themoonisacheese
14684
19462
6031
8392
12142



Average rank / number of contestants (for interest's sake)



Entry
Ten weak players
Two groups
Huge pool
32 skilled players
Average




Spitemaster
.68125
.81127
.95474
.95400
.85032


tsh
.67434
.81092
.94968
.93938
.84333


example
.67882
.80547
.95200
.90096
.83431


Themoonisacheese
.63590
.78026
.78219
.73068
.73226




-1 purely because restricting it to Python, even if it makes the controller easier to run, feels needlessly restrictive.

@ATaco I'd be happy to help translate something into Python.  I simply do not know how to write a controller that could expose a function cross-linguistically.  If you'd like to do that, feel free - and then I could relax that restriction.

You can simply use STDIO, which is a typical solution other controller based challenges utilise. It's generally recommending that users post to the Sandbox before posting their challenges to help with iteration. That said, there's nothing objectively wrong with being Python only, and my -1 only represents my personal opinion.

Most KOTH type challenges are single language only. Though in this case I since it's not a koth I think people should just be able to score themselves

I've personally experienced installing every language people might use is undoable

@ATaco: see my answer for a script you may use to run your submission in any language. I don't anticipate OP to add you to the leaderboard (though i guess the machine a submission is ran on doesn't really matter) but you can at least participate.

@Themoonisacheese That's great! I've updated the repo.

@ATaco Most KOTH contests only run a single programming language.

Bash
This is, short of always returning contestants[0], the worst algorithm possible.
takes the first 4 contestants, runs a game with them. returns the winner of that game.
use with helper.
read numcont
contestants=()
for i in $(seq 1 $numcont); do
    read cont
    contestants+=("$cont")
done
read numgames

echo "run"
echo 4
for i in $(seq 0 3); do
    echo "${contestants[$i]}"
done
results=()
for i in $(seq 0 3); do
    read res
    results+=("$res")
done
echo "ret"
echo "${results[0]}"

Ten weak players    : 14684    0.63590
Two groups          : 19462    0.78026
Huge pool           : 6031    0.78219
32 skilled players  : 8392    0.73068
Average             : 12142    0.73226


Other language helper
put the following code in a file named helper.py:
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
import sys
from time import sleep

sleeptime = 0
def run_tournament(contestants, games, play_game):
    # contestants: an array of contestant names
    # games: a number - this is the maximum number of games you're allowed to play
    # play_game: a function which takes an array of contestants and returns the outcome of a game which they all play
    # returns a single string, expected to be the name of one of the competitors
    process = Popen([arg for arg in sys.argv[2:]], stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, text=True, universal_newlines=True, bufsize=1)
    process.stdin.write(str(len(contestants)) + "\n")
    for c in contestants:
        process.stdin.write(c + "\n")
    process.stdin.write(str(games) + "\n")
    i=0
    while i<games:
        #sleep(sleeptime)
        line = process.stdout.readline().strip()
        if line == "run":
            #sleep(sleeptime)
            numplayers = int(process.stdout.readline())
            players = []
            for j in range(numplayers):
                #sleep(sleeptime)
                players.append(process.stdout.readline().strip())
            res = play_game(players)
            for p in res:
                process.stdin.write(p+"\n")
            i+=1
        elif line == "ret":
            #sleep(sleeptime)
            return process.stdout.readline().strip()
        else:
            raise ChildProcessError("Command not in [run, ret] recieved")
    raise ChildProcessError("No games are left, but never returned")

run using python3 main.py helper $(which <program>) [additional args passed to program...]
From the perspective of your program, the protocol looks like:
STDIN                                    STDOUT
                     init phase:
<number of contestants>
<name of contestant 1>
... repeat n times
<number of games>
                    ->goto loop
                     loop phase:
                                          run
                                          ->goto "run"
                                          (or)
                                          ret
                                          ->goto "ret"
                    "run" phase:
                                          <number of contestants in that game>
                                          <name of contestant 1>
                                          ...repeat n times
<name of winner>
...additional contestants, sorted
                    ->goto loop
                    "ret" phase:
                                          <name of overall winner>
             program is expected to terminate here.

Notes:

If you exceed the max number of games, an exception will be raised and no points will be awarded
If you output something not in [run,ret] during the loop phase, an exception will be raised and no points will be awarded
This is considerably slower than equivalent python implementations. a very basic bash implementation only runs at 240 it/s on my computer, taking 7 minutes to finish a run.
If you find the code hanging, it's probably because the python wrapper is too fast for your program. Set sleeptime to a low value like 0.0005 and uncomment all the sleep() calls. This will make it run even slower, but sometimes you need it to run at all.


Python 3
A, B, C, D, E = 10000.0, 100.0, 1.003, 50.0, 0.95

def choose_player(players):
  name, score, win, lose = players
  return (lose, -win)

def record_result(win, lose):
  win[2] += 1
  lose[3] += 1
  p = 1 - 1 / (1 + C ** (lose[1] - win[1]))
  win[1] += p * B * E ** (win[2] + win[3])
  lose[1] -= p * B * E ** (lose[2] + lose[3])

def run_tournament(contestants, games, play_game):
  map = {c: [c, A, 0, 0] for c in contestants}
  scores = [map[c] for c in contestants]
  for i in range(games):
    players = sorted(scores, key=choose_player)[:4]
    names = [p[0] for p in players]
    result = play_game(names)
    for index, win in enumerate(result):
      for lose in result[:index:-1]:
        record_result(map[win], map[lose])
  final = sorted(scores, key=lambda s: -s[1])
  return final[0][0]

Try it online!

Here's my best attempt:
import random

def run_tournament(contestants, games, play_game):
    contestants = [[x, 0, 0] for x in contestants]
    min_games_played = 0
    remove_per_round = min((len(contestants) - 4) / min(games - 2, games * 0.9), 3)
    to_remove = 0
    while games > 0:
        games -= 1
        options = [x for x in contestants if x[1] == min_games_played]
        if len(options) > 4:
            random.shuffle(options)
            options = options[:4]
        elif len(options) < 4:
            min_games_played += 1
            random.shuffle(contestants)
            options = options + [x for x in contestants if x[1] == min_games_played and x[0] not in options][:4 - len(options)]
        result = play_game([x[0] for x in options])
        for option in options:
            option[1] += 1
            option[2] += result.index(option[0])
        to_remove += remove_per_round
        while to_remove >= 0.99 and len(contestants) > 4:
            to_remove -= 1
            worst_score = max([x[2]/x[1] for x in contestants if x[1] > 0])
            for contestant in contestants:
                if contestant[1] == 0:
                    continue
                if contestant[2] / contestant[1] == worst_score:
                    contestants.remove(contestant)
                    break
    best_score = min([x[2]/x[1] for x in contestants if x[1] > 0])
    for contestant in contestants:
        if contestant[2] / contestant[1] == best_score:
            return contestant[0]
```


def run_tournament(contestants, games, play_game):
    winners = contestants[0:len(contestants)]
    upnext = winners
    # run several elimination rounds
    while True:
        # temp list of winners
        winners = []
        seconds = []
        # run games
        while len(upnext) > 0:
            games -= 1
            # choose size of game:
            if len(upnext) < 4:
                # all that are left
                n = len(upnext)
            elif len(upnext) % 4 > 0:
                # play games of 3 until it's divisible by 4
                n = 3
            else: 
                n = 4
            upnow = upnext[0:n]
            del upnext[0:n]
            # play game
            results = play_game(upnow)
            # record winner
            winners.append(results[0])
            seconds.append(results[1])
        # winners go in next round
        upnext = winners
        # if 4 or fewer winners, go to next stage
        if len(winners) <= 4:
            break
    # second stage: repeated games with finalists:
    finalists = winners + seconds[:(4-len(winners))]
    scores = { nm : 0 for nm in finalists }
    while games > 0:
        games -= 1
        results = play_game(finalists)
        for i in range(len(results)):
            scores[list(results)[i]] += 3-i
    # return winner
    return max(scores, key=scores.get)

